# Creating a 1x1 Julia array

Tags: arrays, julia

I would like to create a 1×1 array (say an `Array{Float64,2}`) and initialize it to some value. Of course this works:

```
M=zeros(1,1)
M[1,1]=0.1234
```

Is there a more concise way to create M and initialize it at the same time?

Comment: Do you actually need to do this? It sounds like you might be trying to use a non-Julian approach from another language.

Answer (score 3):

Since `[1.1234]` will give you a Vector in Julia the simplest way I could come up with is:

```
julia> fill(1.234,1,1)
1x1 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.234
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to reshape:

```
julia> reshape([1.234], 1, 1)
1x1 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.234
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are not what I would recommend. The best way is to use

```
julia> hcat(5)
1×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 5
```

This is most concise and parallels the `[x y]` concatenation form.